# Handle when IE window moves - Visual C++

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-c++, com, atl, bho

I want to handle window move events. My first try was to handle `DWebBrowserEvents2::WindowSetHeight`, `WindowSetLeft`, `WindowSetTop` and `WindowSetWidth` events, but for some reasons, these events didn't get fired at all. I've handled window resize by handling `HTMLWindowEvents2::onresize`. How would I handle when the window moves?

I've also tried implementing `IHTMLOMWindowServices`, but its members are not called when window position changes. Are there any suggestions as to to what would be a good interface to implement? I'm creating an IE extension using ATL in Visual C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handled the situation by using Timer. Not too elegant, but works!

Answer (score 0):

HTML window is not the right place. You need to go one level up to the browser window level, e.g.:

```
            // Get a handle for the IE window and set a hook for the window resize/move events
        m_spWebBrowser->get_HWND(reinterpret_cast<SHANDLE_PTR*>(&m_pWebBrowserHwnd));
        if(m_pWebBrowserHwnd)
        {
            int idHook = WH_CALLWNDPROC; // Type of hook: all Window calls
            HOOKPROC hookProc = MyClass::OnWindowMessage; // Procedure to be called
            HINSTANCE hMod = NULL; // DLL to monitor
            DWORD dwThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(m_pWebBrowserHwnd,NULL); // IE Thread to monitor
            m_ResizeHook = SetWindowsHookEx(idHook, hookProc, hMod, dwThreadId); 
            Trace (L"Hook for window move/resize is set up");
        }
```

Then onWindowMessage handles the right message:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MyClass::OnWindowMessage(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

LRESULT result = CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);

if( (lParam!=NULL) && (nCode == HC_ACTION))
{
    CWPSTRUCT *CwpStruct = (CWPSTRUCT *) lParam;
    switch(CwpStruct->message)
    {
    case WM_MOVE:
        HWND manipluatedHWND = CwpStruct->hwnd;
            //Code to execute when window moves
        break;
    }
}
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this trick didn't work. I set up the WindowsHook (that seems to be okay), but the callback function, OnWindowMessage is never called :(

Comment: Perhaps the callback function needs to be static... Worked for me.

Comment: yeah, the callback function is static. Wouldn't work in any other way.

Comment: No, i meant that the code wouldn't compile without making the OnWindowMessage static. But, the move event still isn't being handled :(

Comment: Hmmm strange. Perhaps you should post the relevant code here so we could scrutinize it...

Comment: Now I see that the code doesn't work in IE8... It worked fine in IE7 :(

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's some rough code

```
    class ATL_NO_VTABLE CHelloWorldBHO :
       public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
       public CComCoClass<CHelloWorldBHO, &CLSID_HelloWorldBHO>,
       public IObjectWithSiteImpl<CHelloWorldBHO>,
       public IDispatchImpl<IHelloWorldBHO, &IID_IHelloWorldBHO, &LIBID_HelloWorldLib, /*wMajor =*/ 1, /*wMinor =*/ 0>,
       public IDispEventImpl<1, CHelloWorldBHO, &DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, &LIBID_SHDocVw, 1, 1>, 
      //Other interfaces here
{

             BEGIN_SINK_MAP(CHelloWorldBHO)
                SINK_ENTRY_EX(1, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE, OnDocumentComplete)//Do stuff OnDocumentComplete
             END_SINK_MAP()

         void STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnDocumentComplete(IDispatch *pDisp, VARIANT *pvarURL){
             //Do other stuff here
             SetUpWindowsHook();//This calls a function that sets a window hook, similar to the code that you've posted
         }

}
```